# Mod Rewrite URL with Number

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite an url from **example.php?id=123** to **example-123-hello-world**
(where "hello-world" is some fake text)

I tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^example-(.*)-(.*)$ /example.php?id=$1
```

it works only if there are no "-" in hello world:

```
example-123-helloworld
```

Any ideas how to do this? thanks a lot! :)

Comment: do you allow any characters for your id? eg: abc_123 is a valid id?

Comment: I didnt know and ID can have non-numeric value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^example-(.*?)-(.*)$ /example.php?id=$1
```

Answer (score 4):

here's what you need to use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^example\-([0-9]+)\-(.*)/?$ example.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```